# Existing maven artifacts not found searching by their sha1

Tags: maven, sonatype, maven-central

I noticed some artifacts cannot be found in maven central from their sha1, while they are in maven central.

For example if I search this [sha1](https://search.maven.org/search?q=1:984B3991D8B881CCFFD46E0E961CADD04511CC8B) it does not return any artifacts, which is odd, because I took this sha1 from [the artifact in maven central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/osgi/org.osgi.util.xml/1.0.2/org.osgi.util.xml-1.0.2.jar.sha1) in the first place.

Not for so many but I noticed this behavior for some artifacts. Is someone know why ?

Comment: First the location for central is https://central.sonatype.org (https://central.sonatype.org/faq/what-happened-to-search-maven-org/)  you might file in a bug .. because neither on the old side nor on the side it seemed to be working...